# Is there anyway to analyze memory dynamically?

Tags: forensics, incident-analysis

I do malware analysis by using memory forensics to gather more useful information but as far as I know, the result of memory acquisition is just one memory dumped for a specific time (snapshot). So, is there anyway or solution to acquire or analyze memory dynamically that including changes?

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use a tool like IDAPro, you can debug your malware and check the content of the memory and registers

- When reaching any pre-selected debug breakpoint
- Instruction per instruction

As mentionned here (https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1470.shtml), you can use IDAPro to take snapshots while you are in a suspended state (waiting in a breakpoint)

So basically you will dynamically see the content of the memory change after each instruction

Comment: I think this is the way to go, I am not aware of any other possibility than debugging, setting breakpoints and then dumping memory content at those breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a [DARPA project](http://opencatalog.darpa.mil/CFT.html) that appears to be what you're looking for. In particular the python based tool [Differential Analysis of Malware in Memory (DAMM)](https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/DAMM) by [504ENSICS Labs](http://www.504ensics.com/)

*Disclaimer, I haven't used it.*